# What is the best way to code a MySQL/PHP script to calculate and deduct expired credits?

Tags: php, mysql

I am programming a website that has a credit table which keeps track of a user's credit in the system. (The value is stored as a float). What I am trying to accomplish is this:

- Credit table has a main credit value (totalcredits) and one for each month in the year, (ex: Feb2014, Mar2014, etc.) that updates with the credits the user earned in a particular month. It also has Feb2014spent, Mar2014spent, etc., which adds credits spent in a particular month.
- What I am trying to do, is after 6 months, if the user did not spend any of their earned credits that were earned 6 months ago, the credits expire. (Deducted from totalcredits in table)

My question is, what is the best way to approach this with MySQL and PHP? For example, if a user spends a fraction of the earned credits from 6 months ago, the script would need to differentiate this so that the user doesn't have too many credits deducted at the expiration period.

I am hoping someone can help point me in the right direction. I appreciate the help!

Comment: Random quick tips: 1) Float is a poor choice to store money (or credits); try decimal 2) No matter what you do on top of that, always keep a detailed history of each individual transaction that affects credit; don't just add/substract to/from the `available_credit` column!

Comment: Thanks Alvaro! I am using decimal on most of it. I also keep a detailed history too, but am curious how to accomplish the 6 month window of where the un-spent credits expire out of their account.

Comment: Can you add the tables you have in your database to the question via. edit please? This will make it a lot easier to give you a solution to your problem as what you are describing currently is rather vague.
Something in the format would be easy to follow => Table name (field 1, field 2, etc...)

Comment: @Justice - Or plain `CREATE TABLE` statements.